# RS485 Eye diagram - does it look good?

Tags: digital-logic, noise, differential, rs485, eye-diagram

I got a new diff probe, I am trying it out on RS485. I'm triggering on the rising edge. The RS485 is running at 25Mhz.

Does the eye diagram look good?

Could I double the speed (50MHz) and be ok? (do I need to worry about overshoot?)

What should one look for in an eye diagram?

[image]

Probe is TEK TDP1000 (1GHz, 200MHz scope) cable length is 1m with 50MHz transcievers.

Comment: Is it normal for the intersection to be so high? What differential probe did you get? I have two HVP70 arriving today at my house.

Comment: I have no idea. A TEK TDP1000. 100$? Can't beat that. I needed something that would do USB 2.0

Comment: Fancy. Fancy. Makes the THDP0200 we have at work look cheap.

Comment: It's nice when the boss wants to use the budget when they don't want to lose it. (and I never said that)

Comment: Maybe this will help. https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9075-D.PDF

Comment: This is a nit, because that eye diagram is good enough even if it's asynchronous.  RS-485 is just an electrical spec.  What's going over the wire?

Comment: @Timwescott 3.3V diff.

Comment: The crossing looks rather high (perhaps an 80ish% duty cycle?) and it seems to  overshoot at the zero and one levels, which typically indicates a bad return loss (and/or impedance discontinuity).

Comment: @KingDuken Would that have anything to do with the scope setup? I was triggering on the rising edge only.

Comment: @VoltageSpike To be honest, I've never verified RS485 signals, I'm just a hardware server engineer. How are you probing this? Are you using a diff pair probe where you can ground very close to ground? (Not that you would want to pay hundreds of dollars for a measly probe) I don't think triggering high causes the overshoot.

Comment: @KingDuken OP says diff probe

Comment: Oops yes. Didn't see that :) Hmm... Perhaps there's a lot of reflection in that line. (Okay, maybe not _a lot_ but there is some indication of some)

Comment: (and to continue a little of what said, darn 5 minute edit rule) Sunnyskyguy also mentioned SNR below which can also be a product from return loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem going to 2f is = 50 Mbps.

The probability of error depends solely on the Voltage becoming the wrong polarity when the discriminator has computed the polarity for that bit..

What affects the SNR? , that determines the BER.

The slew rate indicates a variable amplitude and thus a variable SNR declining signal level, this also means a declining BER.

The 90% Vpp amplitude of data  occurs when the rise time Tr reduces to Tr=0.35/f.  ( by definition)

Since the bit interval, Tb= 2/f,
thus Tr=0.7Tb

Assume from the trace , Tr= 7ns

- then ideal max bit rate “may be” 0.7/7ns =100Mb/s.

However additional margin loss results from pattern dependent Inter-Symbol-Interference, ISI  perhaps from pattern dependency e.g. 011 or 0011 vs 0101 or group delay distortion or random jitter reduces the ideal margin of 100% down to some number like 30% that “may” correlate to some probability of error, or Bit Error Rate, BER = 1e-9. This depends on several other factors beyond the scope of this answer. .

The affect is not visible with a single trace capture, but is visible when displayed with trace memory overwrites.  We know the correlation between Standard Deviation of Gaussian Noise vs number of bits  so this jitter can be measured  on time interval ,TI counters and/or Phase Margin Analyzers or BER Window Margin Analyzers.

Since the visible transition is skewed or asymmetric from  ideal 50% to ~ 90% This amounts to 40% of Tr and thus degrades the Phase Margin by 40% of 7 ns or +/- 2.8ns

Comment: Is this question a good question?

Comment: Not really. A better question has measurable parameters and Design Goals or specs. with uncertainty how to apply them based on limited experience.  This question suggests good image trace skills but nothing more.

Comment: One spec that I have is 50MHz (implied in the OP), what would you do to improve the question?

Comment: Show method of Clk data recovery, cause of Skew, measurements of skew , rise time, jitter with random data p-p over some long time interval.... at least show some understanding of bit error rate and optimization questions with lab tests etc etc and Show length of application vs measurement and compute MHz-m product the preferred limitation of RS485

Comment: Always show assumptions and test measurements.  Like cable type , length, discriminator, probe BW.